# Debug MYSQLI Conversion

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm still a bit new at mysqli so please go easy. I'm trying to convert to MYSQLI and this is what I'm coming up with.

> db_conx.php

```
<?php
$db_conx = mysqli_connect("localhost", "use", "pass", "db");
// Evaluate the connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo mysqli_connect_error();
    exit();
}
?>

<?php
    // Connect to the MySQL database  



include "includes/db_conx.php"; 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM content ORDER BY id DESC";

$result = mysqli_query($db_conx,$sql);
$productCount = mysqli_num_rows($result);

        $blogList = "";
    if ($productCount > 0) {

$adverts = array(
'test',
'test 2');
$counter = 0;

while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqltwo)){
$id = $row["id"];
$article_title = $row["article_title"];
$category = $row["category"];
$author = $row["author"];
$date_added = $row["date_added"];
$article = $row["article"];
$short = substr(strip_tags($article), 0, 750);
$shortTitle = substr(strip_tags($article_title), 0, 45);

if($readmore == ''){
//Code for new post
$blogList .= '<div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="http://www..php?id='.$id.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www./'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
<div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
<div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="http://www..php?id='.$id.'"><img src="http://www.read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>';
}
else{
//Code for old post
$blogList .= '<div class="blogSnippetTitle"><a href="'.$readmore.'"><h2>'.$article_title.'</h2></a></div><div class="blogSnippet"><div class="blogImage"><img src="http://www./'.$id.'.jpg" height="142px" width="200px" alt="'.$category.' '.$shortTitle.'" /></div><div class="blogSnippetPrev"><div class="citation">By <span style="color:#006699;">'.$author.'</span> on <span style="color:#99aacc;">'.$date_added.'</span> in <span style="color:#006699;">'.$category.'</span></div>
<div class="snippet">'.$short.'...<br /></div>
<div class="readMoreButton"><br /><a href="'.$readmore.'"><img src="http://www.read_more.png" alt="read more graphic" /></a></div>
</div>
</div>';
}
if($counter < 2){
$blogList .= $adverts[$counter];
$counter++;
}
}
}
?>
```

The error I'm getting is

> [07-Aug-2013 22:18:26 America/Denver] PHP Warning: 
>   mysqli_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, null
>   given in /home/learnsit/public_html/site-design-blog.php on line 23

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing `sqltwo` in `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` **but** it takes an argument of 
`mysqli_result` like `$result`

Try this,

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
```

in place of

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sqltwo)){
```

Read [mysqli_fetch_assoc()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)